# Show notification in date and time taking from db

Tags: android, realm

I'm try to create android app, todo list with notification about start new event. Create service for show notification, but it's don't work. Service start but notification don't show. Please help.(Taking data from db is working).
Method which called in onStartCommand

```
void timeToDoSomething() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Realm readData = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            EventDTO eventsDTO;
            while (true) {
                Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenuActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                        0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

                GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
                String date = String.valueOf(gregorianCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE))
                        + "-" + String.valueOf(gregorianCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                        + "-" + String.valueOf(gregorianCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat formating = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                eventsDTO = readData.where(EventDTO.class).equalTo("date", date)
                        .and().equalTo("timeStart", formating.format(gregorianCalendar.getTime())).findFirst();

                if(eventsDTO!=null) {
                    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.main_logo)
                            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplication().getResources(), R.drawable.main_logo))
                            .setTicker("Time to do something")
                            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setContentTitle("Time Manager Remember")
                            .setContentText(eventsDTO.getName());

                    Notification notification = builder.build();
                    nm.notify(NOTIF_ID, notification);
                }
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(60);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: what's the msg in logcat ! are you trying on Oreo ,

Comment: If this is the code you write, please add `realm.refresh()` after `while(true)`

Comment: Ty man. I feel so dumb...